# how to create custom zsh commands?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, zsh

I want to make my own zsh commands on my mac. And I have no idea how to do that and how to write shell code. How do I get started? I want to make a basic command like this:

```
myname@My-MacBook-Air  ~ hi
hi, user!
```

Comment: Define what is a `zsh command` . In general, a command is just an executable program, and this can be written in any language - in zsh as well -  and be called from any process. In addition (and with respect to zsh) you can define commands which live only inside your zsh process. Such commands are (somewhat inappropriately) named "zsh functions". Finally, zsh has a feature named _alias_, which allows you to define a shortcut for a longer command. Aliases also live only inside your zsh process. In your case, an `alias hi="echo hi user"` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a bash script and save it in your `/usr/bin/` directory or any other directory. for example:

### Step 1

Create a new file and name it `mycommand.sh`. then write the below code in it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
```

### Step 2

Set an executable access to this file by running this command in the terminal.

```bash
> chmod +x mycommand.sh
```

### Step 3

Make sure the `/usr/bin/` directory is in your PATH by running this command in the terminal.

```bash
> echo $PATH
```

If there is not, visit this [website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-view-and-update-the-linux-path-environment-variable) to learn how to add a directory to the PATH.

### Step 4

Run the command `mycommand` in your terminal and you will see the *"Hello"* string in the terminal.

```bash
> mycommand
Hello
```

You can write more complex scripts in that file and create your own commands.

Comment: Don't give a user, who is asking THIS type of question (which shows that he has zero knowledge on that topic) the recommendation to fiddle with `/usr/bin`. Too risky!

Answer (score 0):

A command alias may also be used to extend command-line functionality:

```
% echo $USER
reb42
% alias hi='echo "hi, $USER."'
% hi
hi, reb42.
% zsh
% hi
zsh: command not found: hi
% echo "alias hi='echo "hi, \$USER."'" >> ~/.zshrc
% zsh
% hi
hi, reb42.
```

edit the `.zshrc` with:

```
open ~/.zshrc
```